# Calling external API through proxy on heroku application

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I have a simple API request in a react app hosted on Heroku.

Locally (localhost:3000) the request works through the proxy configured on my `package.json` but when I deploy the application on Heroku it does not work anymore.
The request return the error: `TypeError: "t.data.facts is undefined"`

The api response is: `{"facts":["A dog’s pregnancy lasts for approximately 60 days."],"success":true}`

My react app code:

```
 class App extends Component {

 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
            dogImage:"",
            dogFact:"",
            isFactLoading: true,
            isImageLoading: true
          }
      }

  componentDidMount(){
        this.getDogImage();
        this.getDogFact();
     }



getDogFact = () =>{
axios.get("/facts")
  .then(res =>{
    this.setState({dogFact:res.data.facts[0]})
    this.setState({isFactLoading:false})
  })
   .catch(err =>{
   console.log(err)
  })
}
```

Render method:

```
render() {
const { dogImage } = this.state;
const { dogFact } = this.state;
const { isImageLoading } = this.state;
const { isFactLoading } = this.state;

return (
  <div className="App">
        <code>{ isImageLoading ? "loading..." :<img src={ dogImage } alt="random dog image"></img> }</code>
        <code>{ isFactLoading ? "loading..." : <p> { dogFact } </p> } </code>
  </div>
);
}
```

My package json code:

```
  "proxy": "https://dog-api.kinduff.com/api/",
```

I set the proxy because of Cross-origin issue, but that only works on my local environment and not on Heroku.

Does anyone knows what could that be?